# How do I load PHP 5.4.3 with Apache 2.2.3?

Tags: php, linux, apache

I have downloaded and installed PHP 5.4.3 via source.  I used the following command line:

```
./configure --with-apxs2 --with-pgsql
```

I have apache 2.2.3 installed, as per:

```
[root@localhost httpd-2.4.2]# apachectl -v
Server version: Apache/2.2.3
Server built:   Apr  4 2010 17:19:54
[root@localhost httpd-2.4.2]#
```

But I get the following error when trying to start my server:

> Starting httpd: httpd: Syntax error on line 206 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load /usr/lib/httpd/modules/libphp5.so into server: /usr/lib/httpd/modules/libphp5.so: undefined symbol: zend_parse_parameters
>                                                              [FAILED]

Answer (score 0):

Did you execute make and make install in php-source directory after configure? This must be done in order to have the module installed for apache.

Comment: Yes, I installed php.  It seems that my Apache does not have zend_parse_parameters, even though it is 2.x, and PHP seems to think it does have that function.  What canI do to work around this?